# Assign a subset of rows in a dataframe with a value (in one column) based on information in another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes: 'data' which contains all the data, 'peak_data' which contains the same columns, with a small selection of the rows.

I have created a column which shows the 'time_difference' between adjacent rows in 'peak_data'.

I want to label the rows (in a column called 'cycles') in 'data' with a number that changes when it gets to the next 'peak' (which is identified by a binary in the 'data' dataframe in a column 'peak') as long as the 'time_difference' in peak_data for that interval is less than 2.

A small example of the 'data' dataframe:

```
       time  pressure_1  pressure_2  ...   accel_z  peak  cycle
0  0.000000    0.245956    0.048084  ...  0.155026     0    NaN
1  0.002000    0.245957    0.047805  ...  0.073971     0    NaN
2  0.002333    0.245984    0.047586  ... -0.056461     0    NaN
3  0.002667    0.246048    0.047464  ...  0.013302     0    NaN
4  0.003000    0.246161    0.047462  ...  0.047970     0    NaN
```

A small example of the 'peak_data' dataframe:

```
       time  pressure_1  pressure_2  ...   accel_z  peak  time_difference
269   1.314    0.134094    0.036958  ... -0.160587   1.0              NaN
555   2.754    0.091645    0.032614  ... -0.514713   1.0            1.440
811   4.064    0.096233    0.049880  ... -0.433658   1.0            1.310
1057  5.300    0.094882    0.032966  ... -0.867374   1.0            1.236
1304  6.522    0.107792    0.040102  ... -0.503299   1.0            1.222
```

What I would like to see is this for the rows after the first peak has been identified (before that I don't want to label the data). For the next interval I'd want it to be labelled '2' and then '3' etc.

```
       time    pressure_1  pressure_2  ...   accel_z  peak  cycle
265  1.294000    0.141472    0.033975  ... -0.027896     0    NaN
266  1.299000    0.140781    0.034691  ... -0.110416     0    NaN
267  1.304000    0.139336    0.035434  ... -0.103580     0    NaN
268  1.309000    0.137103    0.036195  ...  0.159482     0    NaN
269  1.314000    0.134094    0.036958  ... -0.160587     1    1
270  1.322000    0.130359    0.037705  ... -0.489627     0    1
271  1.329000    0.125974    0.038417  ... -0.832096     0    1
272  1.332000    0.121045    0.039078  ... -0.639713     0    1
273  1.334000    0.115730    0.039676  ... -0.565494     0    1
274  1.339000    0.110218    0.040197  ... -0.475040     0    1
```

This is the code that deals with the problem outlined:

```
data['cycle'] = np.nan

cycle_num = 1

for index, row in peak_data.iterrows():        
    if peak_data.loc[index,'time_difference'] == np.nan:
        pass
    elif peak_data.loc[index,'time_difference'] < 2:
        start = peak_data.loc[index,'index'] 
        end = peak_data.loc[index,'index']
        data.loc[start : end,'cycle'] = cycle_num
        cycle_num += 1
```

The code above gives me a KeyError: 'index', previously I've had it as 'time' and I'm just not sure why.

Is this the way I should be approaching the problem, or is there a better way? Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to to create a small, very simple dataset to test this logic on.  For example.  You don't need the pressure columns in your test dataset.

Comment: Doing it simply, doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't do what I'm hoping to achieve using the same logic. That is what I'm stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the integer index labels of the `peak_data` DataFrame exactly correspond to the index labels of the target rows in `data`. If that's always true for your full dataset, then something this should work:

```
# Initialize column of all nan
data['cycle'] = np.nan

# Get index labels for short (< 2 s) and
# long (>= 2 s) peaks
short_peaks = peak_data[peak_data['time_difference'] < 2].index
long_peaks = peak_data[peak_data['time_difference'] >= 2].index

# Label short-peak rows with 1, long with -1
data.loc[short_peaks, 'peak'] = 1
data.loc[long_peaks, 'peak'] = -1

# 
data['cycle'] = data['peak'].cumsum()

# Hack: build a flag column that labels ALL rows
# belonging to a short peak with 1, and ALL rows
# belonging to a short peak with -1
data['flag'] = data['peak'].ffill()

# Finally, overwrite the "cycle" value with -1 for all rows
# belonging to a long peak, then replace -1 with nan
data.loc[data['flag'] == -1, 'cycle'] = data['flag'].replace(-1, np.nan)

# Drop the flag column
data = data.drop(columns='flag')
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you. So much simpler than what I've been trying! The issue with this is that I want to keep the 'cycles' column as NaN between the intervals that are bigger than 2. So, for all the rows that are in that longer interval - those I want to stay as NaN, and then carry on the counter from where we left off in the next interval. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @ShrutiTurner, sorry for the delay. I've updated the answer with a somewhat clumsy approach that I hope nevertheless works.